# VScode theme install walkthrough

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I downloaded this kick ass theme for VScode. Problem is, I can't figure out how to install it. Every youtube video or forum post I find shows me how to install using the extension feature, but none offer any usable info on how to install a theme manually using the VScode settings and files that I've downloaded. It would really be helpful if someone could help me with a step by step on how to install this theme. Thanks in advance

THEME:[New-York-Theme credit"Bernardi23"](https://github.com/Bernardi23/New-York-Theme/tree/master)

Comment: on github page copy settings.json contents without brackets and open settings in vs code and click something like edit settings.json. then paste after first bracket, save and restart. it should work. Also make backup of settings.json.

Comment: @RocketNikita I tried that out, but it defaulted back to the original VScode theme

Comment: Themes are supposed to be distributed as extensions, and this one isn't. To be honest, I'd just find a better theme.

Comment: You can also customize your vscode with your favorite colors, check a try of mine here: https://github.com/mostafero/vscode-ubuntu-theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrapped the `NewYork.json` file from the git repo by Lucas Bernardi in an extension that you can install from inside VSC.

In the `Extension Bar` search for `new york` and you can see

[New York](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.theme-New-York)

Comment: Thanks! You're the best! I was able to find a Black theme with transparency using Glassit-VSC. This way I can use it even on light colored backgrounds.